# 'drupalSettings' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, drupal, npm, yarnpkg

I have a singe page app that I want to run in every drupal node of a specific content type.

The app is made in react using yarn.

In my index.js file I am trying to do the following:

```
if(window.location.href !== 'http://localhost:3002/') {
  console.log(drupalSettings);
}
```

However `npm run build` or `yarn build` are both giving me `'drupalSettings' is not defined  no-undef`.

How can I force npm/yarn to ignore this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using yarn or similar you need to let eslint know that the variable is coming from the global scope.  From the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef):

```
/*global someFunction b:true*/
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/

var a = someFunction();
b = 10;
```

Where the `b:true` indicates that `b` can be changed within the scope of this file.  For something like `drupalSettings` the `:true` could be optional since you are most likely pulling info from the page and not setting anything.

For your specific use you would use

```
/*global drupalSettings:true*/
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/

console.log(drupalSettings)
```

and you would see the  output in your browser's console.